# Updating an item inside of JComponent container

Tags: java, swing, jcomponent

Sorry for no code.

1. Class `CustomThing` extends `JComponent`. Inside it, a new `JLabel` is added. The label needs to be updated from a text box in an outside class. How should I access the label's `setText` method so that the text box would update the label properly?
2. Same as 1, except that class `CustomThing` is a child class of `DaddyCustomThing`. `CustomThing` is created as:

   ```
   DaddyCustomThing thing = new CustomThing();
   ```

Any tips welcome. I would add some code, but I'm terrible at writing it and due to that it might make the issue more confusing, not less.

PS. The purpose of this is to understand `JComponent` better and to fix my university project with obtained knowledge.

Comment: *"it might make the issue more confusing"* And it might not. Post a [mcve] so we can get information from, or ignore (if it's as confusing as you imply), it. Voting to close. I'll reverse the vote if you [edit] to add an MCVE (& let me know).

Comment: @Andrew Thompson

For some reason, it is generally assumed that I could make up an MCVE in 5 minutes. Not really. It would probably take me at least a few hours, to maybe or not maybe add some clarity to a question that may or may not get answered.

About closing the question - if I cannot produce an MCVE, I don't deserve to ask then? It seems to be what you are implying. Is StackOverflow forbidden for people who can't produce MCVEs now? I don't understand.

Comment: *" For some reason, it is generally assumed that I could make up an MCVE in 5 minutes."* Wow, 5 minutes? Who assumes that? Seriously. If you are not prepared to put an hour or two into making an MCVE, you're really not doing sufficient to warrant me looking at your problem. I expect there are others that feel the same way. But it's something you should do before asking a question, rather than making pithy apologies and not posting one, as this already has 3 close votes. I know at least two of those are for the close reason that mentions 'no MCVE'.

Comment: The policy about mcve as stated in posts closure page: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See mcve". I find mvce a very useful technique. Not only it makes helping much easier, it 
is a powerful **debugging and testing** tool. It many case, while preparing one, you are likely to find a solution yourself.

Comment: @AndrewThompson as mentioned in another comment, I apologize for wasting your time. Now it became a lot clearer to me what kind of format StackOverflow has now and that I'm not qualified to be using it. This is not sarcasm - it was genuinely my mistake. Honestly, thank you for help me understand that I should seek help elsewhere as the site no longer caters to beginners. Best of luck to you and thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

All accesses to UI component should be made in the "Event Dispatch Thread" (EDT) so you might want to check [`SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater(java.lang.Runnable)) et.al. :

```
final String newVal = "toto";
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() {
        myLabel.setText(newVal);
    }
});
```

Please note the `final` modifier on the value you want to set, as a sub-class is created.

You probably have better ways to do it with lambda in Java 8, but the idea stays the same.

Comment: Thank you. I will start researching it right now. Thank you for not needing an MCVE and still being able to provide some information!

Comment: @Governator in many cases it is possible to provide some information without mcve. However it is not necessarily useful information. I am guessing that this answer is not going to help you, but it is only a guess because the information provided is partial. Partial information is a waste of time of those good people who voluntarily try to help.

Comment: @c0der You are right about this answer not being the solution I've implemented, but it did give me some good ideas while I was researching the subject. I appreciate the time of people who are genuinely trying to help, but it seems that StackOverflow grew into "professional answers for professional questions" kind of place which (as a beginner) I'm not qualified to use. Once again, I apologize for taking your time and misunderstanding the format of this place. Now it is clear to me that should seek help elsewhere until I am of a reasonable caliber to form questions here.